# ASP.NET Dynamic Data: Access rights only to specific rows

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, authorization, dynamic-data

I want to use ASP.NET Dynamic Data for my next project, but there is a problem a can't manage to solve. In the database we manage authorization on a per-row basis. For example no user is permitted to see all rows of the Contracts table. So there is a Many to Many Relationship between Contracts and Users. So everytime Dynamic Data performs a Select to show all Contracts it has to look into the ContractUsers junction table to see what contracts the current user is permitted to see (filtered by UserID which will be stored in a session variable). Of course these junction tables should be invisible to the users. 
By default Dynamic Data returns all rows of a table, so is it possible to customize this behaviour for every query the user performs?
I want to use Dynamic Data together with LINQ to SQL but if this task would much easier to accomplish using Entity Framework I would look into that too.

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing such a solution in Dynamic Data it will probably require the creation of a custom Entity Template; not really easy but once done it will not require the creation of custom pages just the editing of the page templates.

I think it will be really usefull to check the excellent work on DD done by S.J.Naughton and presented on his [blog](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net).

Greetings, F.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use dynamic data because you need full control over querying and manually write all linq queries to add your data level security. If you still insist on dynamic data be aware that you will still write most of pages yourselves and you will only use dynamic templates. You will have to manually define ever data source and correctly pass where condition to filter results based on logged user.

In addition linq-to-sql is not able to hide junction table and entity framework is able to do that only if junction table contains just two FKs for many-to-many relation. If this table contains any other column you want to use in the application you will have to map it as any other entity and dynamic data will show it as an entity.

Dynamic data are technology for quick creation of simple application where you need to provide access to database through web interface but what you describe is not a simple scenario. You need per record authorization which can differ among entity types.

Comment: But if I am not using Dynamic Data I still would have to implement all this by myself. I thought that Dynamic Data would at least be a good framework to use.

Comment: Yes you will have to implement it yourselves.

Comment: So this wouldn't be a disadvantage, because I can't get around the implementation. But maybe Dynamic Data makes life easier at some other points.